# dtype of DataFrame object instead of int

Tags: python, pandas, types

How do I get the dataframe to interpret types in the construtor? As of now, it keeps everything as "object"

Here is my code right now:

```
arr = list(range(120)) + [21]*100
cat = ["A"]*20 + ["B"]*40 + ["C", "D"] * 20 + ["E", "F" ,"G"] * 30
df = pd.DataFrame([arr]*3 + [cat], index = ["a1", "a2", "a3", "cat"]).T
print(df.a1.dtype.name)
print(df.a3.dtype.name)
print(df.cat.dtype.name)

object
object
object
```

Comment: `df.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True).dtypes` or `df.head(1).applymap(type)`?

Comment: will that keep the string variable the same?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
np_array = np.array([arr]*3 + [cat])
dict = {"a1":np_array[0], "a2":np_array[1], "a3":np_array[2]}
df = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame({"cat":np_array[3]}), pd.DataFrame(dict, dtype = 'int64')], names = ["a1", "a2", "a3", "cat"], axis = 1)
```

Comment: Dont have an open core rn, but will the array of strings break it?

Comment: That is some very, very case specific code.  I was mostly looking for something to interpret types automagically :) I figured out another hack somewhere else to fix the problem.  When I compare types, I use np.subclass(s.dtype, np.number) and it does the rest